# Webscraping Square Website For Available Product

Tags: java, html, discord, twitch

I'm working on building a discord bot for a twitch community that can access the community stores Square Website and return messages to a discord channel when the quantity changes (someone buys something or the store is restocked). I'm trying to use Jsoup with Maven but I'm not overly familiar with html and how to pull the individual quantity elements and integrate them into the program. In the code below I think I have the basic structure but I need to know how to include all the different products available

Item example: https://suknives.square.site/product/pokemon-50-pack-mixer-team-up-evolving-skies-brilliant-stars/232?cs=true&cst=custom

```
private static int scrapeProductAvailability(String productUrl) throws IOException {
        Document productPage = Jsoup.connect(productUrl).get();

        // Replace these selectors with the actual HTML elements that contain availability information
        Element availabilityElement = productPage.selectFirst("");
        
        // Extract the availability information from the element
        if (availabilityElement != null) {
            String availabilityText = availabilityElement.text();
            
            // Parse the availability text to get the quantity (this is just a simplified example)
            int availability = Integer.parseInt(availabilityText);
            
            return availability;
        }
        
        // Return a default value if availability information is not found
        return -1;
    }
```